# subprocess and Type Str doesnt support the buffer API

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.3

I have

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen('dir',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
  columns = line.split(' ')
  print (columns[3])
```

have error in line 3 Type Str doesnt support the buffer API.

What am i doing wrong i am on Python 3.3

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are reading binary data, not `str`, so you need to decode the output first. If you set the `universal_newlines` argument to `True`, then `stdout` is automatically decoded using the result of the [`locale.getpreferredencoding()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)
 (same as for opening text files):

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(
    'dir', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    columns = line.decode().split()
    if columns:
        print(columns[-1])
```

If you use Python 3.6 or newer, you can use an explicit `encoding` argument for to the `Popen()` call to specify a different codec to use, like, for example, UTF-8:

```
cmd = subprocess.Popen(
    'dir', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
for line in cmd.stdout:
    columns = line.split()
    if columns:
        print(columns[-1])
```

If you need to use a different codec in Python 3.5 or earlier, don't use `universal_newlines`, just decode text from bytes explicitly.

You were trying to split a `bytes` value using a `str` argument:

```
>>> b'one two'.split(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

By decoding you avoid that problem, and your `print()` call will not have to prepend the output with `b'..'` either.

However, you probably just want to use the `os` module instead to get filesystem information:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks it works but any idea why i am getting list index out of range error

Comment: @NickLoach: the line has fewer than 3 columns?

Comment: Thanks Martijn the line has ['03-04-2013', '', '19:48', '', '', '', '<DIR>', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '.ipython\r\n'] i want the feild called .ipython as output

Comment: Why not use `os.listdir()` instead?

Comment: I made a simple example the command i would be running will not be a os command but a binary that outputs something on the above lines

Comment: @NickLoach: You need to use `.split()` (no argument) to split on variable whitespace; it'll remove the `\r\n` too, and not include all the individual spaces. I used `[-1]` in my example to select the *last* element.

Comment: Interesting when i used [-1] like your code i get IndexError: list index out of range :-)

Comment: @NickLoach: That's because you seem to have empty lines in your output. I added a simple test.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution of the first part of [Martijn Pieters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817457/1872673) is to pass the `universal_newlines=True` argument to the `Popen` call.

I would even simplify this to:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('dir', universal_newlines=True)
columns = output.split()
print(columns)
```

**NOTE**: If file or directory names contain spaces, use `os.listdir('.')` as suggested in [Martijn Pieters's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15817457/1872673) or something like the following:

```
output = subprocess.check_output('dir', universal_newlines=True)
columns = []
for e in output.split():
    if len(columns) > 0 and columns[-1].endswith('\\'):
        columns[-1] = columns[-1][:-1] + " " + e
    else:
        columns.append(e)
print(columns)
```

Comment: `dir` is an internal command on Windows i.e., if there is no `dir.exe` then `shell=True` is necessary in this case.

Comment: If we assume one-column output then you could use `.splitlines()`, to handle paths with spaces

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, agreed. I didn't use `.splitlines()` since my version of `dir` *(GNU coreutils) 8.21* produces output in multiple columns.

Comment: `dir` produces a single column output if stdout is redirected (as it is the case with `stdout=PIPE`). Try `dir | cat`, to see it in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

Better use [binascii.b2a_uu](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html) that converts binary data to a line of ASCII characters

```
from binascii import b2a_uu 
cmd = b2a_uu(subprocess.Popen('dir',shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE))
```