# Python - Getting and setting clipboard data with subprocesses

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, clipboard, multiplatform

I recently discovered from [this post](http://www.macdrifter.com/2011/12/python-and-the-mac-clipboard.html) a way to get and set clipboard data in python via subprocesses, which is exactly what I need for my project.

```
import subprocess

def getClipboardData():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['pbpaste'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    retcode = p.wait()
    data = p.stdout.read()
    return data

def setClipboardData(data):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['pbcopy'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.stdin.write(data)
    p.stdin.close()
    retcode = p.wait()
```

However it only seems to work on the OS X operating system. How can I recreate this functionality across windows, mac and linux?

**UPDATE**

Using my original code and the windows solution bigbounty provided, I guess I only need a solution for linux now. Perhaps something utilizing xclip or xsel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Linux you could use your original code using the [`xclip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xclip) utility instead of `pbpaste`/`pbcopy`:

```
import subprocess

def getClipboardData():
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xclip','-selection', 'clipboard', '-o'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    retcode = p.wait()
    data = p.stdout.read()
    return data

def setClipboardData(data):
    p = subprocess.Popen(['xclip','-selection','clipboard'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.stdin.write(data)
    p.stdin.close()
    retcode = p.wait()
```

`xclip`'s parameters:

- `-selection clipboard`: operates over the clipboard selection (X Window have multiple "[clipboards](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html)"
- `-o`: read from desired selection

You should notice that this solution operates over [binary data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817420/subprocess-and-type-str-doesnt-support-the-buffer-api). To storing a string you can use:

```
setClipboardData('foo'.encode())
```

And lastly if you are willing to use your program within a shell piping look my question about a [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44553539/python-script-using-subprocess-and-xclip-hangs-if-piped-in-bash).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I already found an alternative method for solving my problem.

Answer (score 2):

For windows,

```
import win32clipboard

# set clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('testing 123')
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

# get clipboard data
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
print data
```

Single library across all platforms - http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/

Comment: I took a look at pyperclip earlier. Does this still have the same get and set functionality as win32, or is it only limited to copying and pasting strings?

Comment: I haven't tried it actually.But I found the idea interesting

Comment: Just checked the source code. Only functions are `copy()` and `paste()`

Comment: May be not robust..better write seperate programs