# Python script using subprocess and xclip hangs if piped in bash

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, piping, xclip

I have a python script that needs to output some values to stdin and copies another string to clipboard. I'm using the module `subprocess` to execute the `xclip` utility through `Popen` something like this:

```
# clip.py
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

print('PRINT_ME')
p1 = Popen(['xclip', '-selection', 'clipboard'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.communicate(input=('PASTE_ME'.encode()))
```

The script works as intended: `PRINT_ME` is echoed in bash and `PASTE_ME` is available to paste, and returns imediatly.

A problem appears when the script output is piped to another command. Suppose one wants to redirect to a file and stdin using `tee`:

```
$ python clip.py|tee file.txt
```

The program works as supposed but not returns, i.e. shell don't give control back.

How can this could be fixed?

**Some important info**: the `xclip` utility **forks** itself (to cope with implementation of clipboards on X) maintaining the string avaliable to copy, when used in shell it returns immediately (it forks to background). It appears that the shell is attaching both `clip.py` and `xclip` stdin/stdout to `tee`.
If `xclip -selection clipboard` is found using `ps u` and killed the command returns.

I'm using Python 3.4.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not due to forking of `xclip`, it's due to how Python handles `Popen.wait()` (which is invoked with your call to `communicate()`) - from Python perspective `xclip` (silent by default) didn't close its stream so it waits... That's why everything works except for Python moving past your `p1.communicate()` line when piping its streams to something else (`tee` in this case) - it waits for all of its file handles to close...

You can either manually open and close your streams, or just configure `xclip` to filter STDIN to STDOUT and keep Python happy:

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen(['xclip', '-selection', 'clipboard', '-f'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.communicate(input=('PASTE_ME'.encode()))
# etc.
```

Didn't test it, but it should work. If you don't want for `xclip` to print out to your current STDOUT just redirect it when instantiating `subprocess.Popen()` to `None` (or `subprocess.DEVNULL` for Python 3.x) or to any other stream handle you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both ways worked fine! I've tested various modifications and found interesting that any code after `p1.communicate` (in the original defective code) are executed, the program halts to exit. And from the two solutions proposed which is more 'pythonic' and side-effects free?

Comment: You're right, I've expressed myself badly - Popen opens a FH for xclip's STDOUT (and ties it to the current STDOUT) and since `xclip` never closes the stream it keeps waiting in the end so it can cleanly exit the subprocess. As for _Pythonic_ - it is an illusive term that means different things to different people, but most people tend to agree that KISS approach is the epitome of being _Pythonic_ - thus, unless you need to do something fancy with STDIN/STDOUT, just use `Popen.communicate()` and save yourself some trouble when `xclip` already allows you to set it up to play nicely with Python.